# SSRS 2005 - Column Toggle Item

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportingservices-2005

I am stuck in developing my report. Can someone please help me ?

Apparently, I have problem with the COLUMN TOGGLE ITEM.

My original report design is like this:

[image: MY ORIGINAL DESIGN]
[(Original here)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27303579/Original.JPG)

However, when I click on the toggle item (TEXTBOX 1), my report looks like this (which I think is wrong):

[image: MY PROBLEM]
[(Original here)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27303579/Problem.JPG)

> MY PROBLEM IS: when all the textbox is OPEN and I click on the TEXTBOX
>   1, not all the textbox under TEXTBOX 1 is CLOSE.

I wish to make my report look like this when the TEXTBOX 1 is pressed (close all the textbox under TEXTBOX1):

[image: DESIRED SOLUTION]

[(Original here)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27303579/Solution.JPG)

I hope I make myself clear. I desperately need help here.

> Dont worry about my ROW DATA. (It works fine)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I Understand Your Problem,In SSRS 2008 R2 you take for this MATRIX item then you place the all the values in that matrix,then next you go to GROUPing pane then group the data by column wise and row wise 
then next taggeled the values in grouping pane 
--->meance---->goto grouping pane--->rightclick on CHILD group----properties---->visibulity----->check the hidden---->and finally give the taggeled value
then it will works like tyou want

Comment: Is it possible to do in SSRS 2005? Also, can I use TABLE instead of MATRIX ??

Comment: yes possible but grouping concept is diffarent in 2008 and 2005